# Is it OK to run automated UI tests (w/ Selenium) asychronously?

Tags: selenium, asynchronous, automated-tests, nunit

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to create automated UI TestMethod(s) w/ Selenium.
Because of the benefit of using await Task.Delay(n) I decided to make my test methods async.
Is there any risks/concerns/issues with running ALL (or more than 1) UI tests asynchronously?

Comment: Rule of thumb would be to make any async methods async all the way through... meaning any methods called inside that method should also be async...  you'll have the benefit of non-blocking calls on the thread(s) used for your code.  On the webdriver side of things, everything has a specific sequence... go to a url, click this link, check for condition, etc.. etc...  those commands need to be sent one at a time (which it will as long as you await each driver call...the webdriver commands to browser also await promises for the most part).

Comment: There won't actually be a point to doing any await async calls unless something else is using the thread(s).  In most cases Selenium code runs like a script that only has the one concern... to communicate with a single webdriver which in turn uses wire protocol (not an async protocol) to communicate with the browser.   Since so much of the action occurs at the webdriver you might find that it's not worth the extra typing.  If you are multi-threading (one webdriver/browser pair per thread) and also have a main thread doing other things you might benefit from async calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally use to run several tests in parallel to reduce the total run time, so you definitely can run tests asynchronously, however you will have to define the test cases for each test in a way so as will be no collisions between the simultaneously running tests.